# Runtime Arrays using Create

Tags: arrays, delphi

Say i have

```
ArrayOfTXSDecimal = array of TXSDecimal;
```

Then during runtime i do

```
Ids := ArrayOfTXSDecimal.create(14450);
```

What did i just create?  an array(ids) with 14450 indexs or just index 14450

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating a dynamic array with one element whose value is 14450.  You are doing the equivalent of this:

```
SetLength(Ids, 1);
Ids[0] := 14450;
```

This `Create()` syntax for dynamic arrays is [documented on Embarcadero's DocWiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Dynamic_Arrays):

> An alternative method of allocating memory for dynamic arrays is to invoke the array constructor:
>
> ```
> type
>   TMyFlexibleArray = array of Integer;
>
> begin
>   MyFlexibleArray := TMyFlexibleArray.Create(1, 2, 3 {...});
> end;
> ```
>
> which allocates memory for three elements and assigns each element the given value.

Comment: so if i run this again with value 22223 then i would have Ids[0] and Ids[1]. or does it over write [0]

Comment: You would be assigning a newly allocated array to `ids`.

Comment: @user41758: *so if I run this again* Why don't you just use the debugger and find out yourself? It would be much faster than waiting for an answer here, and you'd learn something in the process about solving problems or finding answers yourself.